# Nested FOR with variables

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm attempting to write a batch script that will go through a list of computers, read a file from the computer, delim the file name, then echo the computer name and the file name result. The issue I'm having is getting the computer name variable to populate in the nested FOR /R command. Here is my script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET LIST=Computers.txt
FOR /F %%A IN (%LIST%) DO (
    FOR /R \\%%A\c$\folder1\folder2 %%B IN (*.txt) DO (
        FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%C IN ("%%B") DO (ECHO %%A %%C
        )
    )
)
EndLocal
```

The filename is something like RB-C1SRC20160716CL.P17.txt. So the result I am looking for is

```
MyPCName P17
```

But I get a blank result. What I have found is that %%A var is being populated from the text file but the %%A var in the FOR /R is not populating. If I ECHO ON the FOR commands I'm seeing FOR /R \%a\folder1\folder2 instead of FOR /R \MyPCName\folder1\folder2. This breakdown is keeping the rest of the script from working properly.

Comment: Related: [Get size of the sub folders only using batch command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397052)

Answer (score 4):

The root directory of a `for /R` command cannot be given by another `for` variable (like `%%I`) nor a variable using delayed expansion (`!VAR!`), unfortunately. You need to specify it either iterally, by a normally expanded variable (`%VAR%`) or by an argument reference (`%1`, `%2`,...).

A good work-around is to place the `for /R` loop in a sub-routine and use `call` to call it from your main routine. The (variable holding the) root path needs to be passed as an argument to `call`. In the sub-routine it is referred to by an argument reference (like `%1`).

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397052) of the post "[Get size of the sub folders only using batch command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38396348)" to see how this can be accomplished.

Another option is to temporarily change into the root directory before the `for /R` loop, which then defaults to the current working directory. Use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)`"\\%%A\c$\folder1\folder2"` to change to the target directory, then put [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) behind the `for /R` loop to return to the former directory.